# Removing end slash from Uri.Segment.Last()?

Tags: c#, .net, uri

What is the safest way to get the last segment of a `System.Uri` while excluding an optional end slash? For example, I have these URL:

```
http://example.com/test/12345
http://example.com/test/12345/
```

I wish to get just the "12345" from the final segment, however, calling `Segments.Last()` will return different strings. In the first case I get "12345" but in the second case I get "12345/".

This is what I have, but doesn't seem very clean, and I'm worried I'm going to be violating the URI spec by not taking some weird edge cases into account:

```
public static string Test(Uri link)
{
    return link.Segments.Last().Replace("/", "");
}
```

Edit: Absolutely ridiculous that this is being flagged for closing

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can simply use a [`TrimEnd()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.trimend):

```
public static string Test(Uri link)
{
    return link.Segments.Last().TrimEnd('/');
}
```